# Load xml file when application is running

Tags: android, xml

Excuse me for my english,i'm not very well

I have a problem,
I develloped application which use XML file, i load it from (res/xml) and there is another way is to load it from ( assests ), whereas, this methode permit to load the file only one time is when the application start( the path is defined at the beginning)

I want to load the XML file when the application is running from the PC, each time i copy a new file to android and the application must read it.
Is there a possibilite to do it ? Where i should put the file?
Can i load it from server of storage or other server?

Please, Help me :(

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it on server and load from there. Here are some example to do that

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/ 
http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html